# LLDB: Set breakpoint at offset from function start using python api

Tags: python, scripting, lldb

I have a lldb python module with a simple setup:

```
def __lldb_init_module (debugger, dict):
    target = debugger.GetSelectedTarget()
    target.DeleteAllBreakpoints()
    process = target.GetProcess()
```

I can easily set a breakpoint at the start of a function using:

```
breakpoint = target.BreakpointCreateByName("functionName", "moduleName")
breakpoint.SetScriptCallbackFunction( "python_module.bp_hit" )
```

and I know this works because my bp_hit function is called correctly.

However, I really need the breakpoint set at X number of bytes from the start of the address of functionName. If I knew the address of the functionName, I could simply add X to the address and use BreakpointCreateByAddress.

What is the python code that will provide me the address of the functionName?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SBTarget::FindFunctions to find the SBSymbolContext(s) that match a your function name.  That returns a list of SBSymbolContext matches (since there may be more than one.)  SBSymbolContext::GetStartAddress will give you an SBAddress for the start of that symbol.  Then use SBAddress::OffsetAddress to add your offset.  There is a SBTarget::CreateBreakpointByAddress but annoyingly enough it only takes an lldb::addr_t not an SBAddress.  You can get an lldb::addr_t from an SBAddress with SBAddress::GetLoadAddress() passing in your target.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Jim's answer is to use the FindSymbols function of SBTarget.